# How come alert breaks javascript execution?

Tags: javascript

how is that possible that call to the alert function changes behavior of a js script? Something like that:

```
function add_token (item) {
    var li_data = $.data(item.get(0), "tokeninput");
```

works but this:

```
function add_token (item) {
    alert('a');
    var li_data = $.data(item.get(0), "tokeninput");
```

doesn't - I get following error in firebug: li_data is undefined jquery.tokeninput.js Line 336 (adding alert call is the only change)

(as you can see I'm playing with Tokenizing Autocomplete jQuery plugin - http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/ )

Now that's something that bugs me. Can someone explain to me how is that even possible?

UPDATE: I tried using Chrome instead of Firefox and this particular problem doesn't appear. So now what? It should be considered some kind of a bug in FF or is there something else about this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: give us more code. the error you showed would only occur if li_data was read, and its not read in your code

Comment: li_data is accessed in the very next line actually, like that:

var li_data = $.data(item.get(0), "tokeninput");
var this_token = insert_token(li_data.id, li_data.name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure speculation, but the fact that it's for an autocomplete thing makes me wonder if the fact that alert is stealing the focus is screwing anything up.  Is there perhaps an onblur event that is firing at the wrong time?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Darth - probably a focus related issue.

If you need to see value of your script as it executes, use [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) instead

```
function add_token (item) {
    console.log('a');
    var li_data = $.data(item.get(0), "tokeninput");
```

Comment: Yes - you are both right. There was blur event fired which set item to null. :)

The reason it worked in Chrome was that Chrome executed blur event after li_data was read.

Thanks - I'm just starting with js and it would take me looong time to come up with the answer myself.